# Complete local domain + $(R_1)$+ depth $2$+ dimension $3$+ $Cl(R)=0 \implies$ normal (hence UFD)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, divisors-algebraic-geometry

For a Noetherian, separated integral scheme $X$ that is regular in codimension $1$, let $Cl(X)$ denote it's (Weil) divisor class group.  For such an affine- scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, let us write $Cl(R):=Cl(\operatorname{Spec}(R))$.

Now I know that if $R$ is a normal domain and $Cl(R)=0$ then $R$ is a UFD. But I'm not sure if one can remove the hypothesis "normal". So here's my question:

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian  complete ($\mathfrak m$-adically)
local domain of depth $2$ and dimension $3$ such that $R_P$ is regular for every height $1$ prime ideal $P$ of $R$ (i.e. $R$ satisfies $(R_1)$). If $Cl(R)=0$, then is $R$ necessarily a UFD (or equivalently, is $R$ necessarily normal) ?

If there is a counter-example, then it must be non Cohen-Macaulay, because Cohen-Macaulay local ring of depth $\ge 2$ implies $S_2$ so along with the $R_1$ assumption, the ring would be normal, hence $R$ would be a UFD if the divisor class group is trivial.

Comment: It's well-known that for a noetherian domain, UFD is equivalent to normal plus vanishing class group (see [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFT), Hartshorne II.6.2, Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra Ch7 S3, etc). Thus the answer to your question is no, and you can find a counterexample by finding a ring which is $R_1$ but not $S_2$ and has vanishing class group. (I don't have such a counterexample off the top of my head.)

Comment: @KReiser: yes, the point of my question really is if I can find such an $(R_1)$ complete local domain of depth at least $2$, with trivial divisor class group which doesn't satisfy $(S_2)$ ... but I'm not content with only saying "such an example definitely exists" unless I actually see and verify one ...